# Joomla order MySQL records with NULLs first

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

How can I use MySQL `IS NOT NULL` in a Joomla query?

My table has the following columns:

```
id, name, desc, effective from, effective to
```

The `effective_to` column can be `NULL`.

I need to have rows with `NULL` in the `effective_to` column first (the event lasts) and rows with timestamp record in column `effective_to` `order by DESC`.

My query:

```
->order($db->quoteName('effective_to') . ' IS NOT NULL ', $db->quoteName('effective_to') . ' DESC ');
```

but it does not work right.

can anyone please help me? I wasn't able to find any examples in the Joomla documentation.

Comment: Please describe exactly what "does not work right" means. Does it give you an error? Do you get an unexpected behaviour, and if so, what is it?

Comment: no, no error. it looks like the ORDER command is totally ignored, or there is a DB sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You are clubbing where clause with order clause. Change it like this.

```
$query
  ->where($db->qn('effective_to') . ' IS NOT NULL')
  ->order($db->qn('effective_to') . ' DESC ');
```